# Get extension from filename like variable - JavaScript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a varable `var file = "testfile.txt";` I am using the following script to find its extension and it works well:

```
var parts = file.split('.');
var flename = parts[0];
var ext = parts[1];
```

But if i have a filename with more than one dots, the logic sucks.. It will give `txt` for `filename.txt`, but not in the case of `file.nam.e.txt` or something else.

Anybody suggest me the simplest solution to do this using JavaScript and/or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
var ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

And as for the file name:

```
var flename = parts.slice(0, parts.length - 1).join(".");
```

Last but not least, I would also validate before that  block of code that `file` is not empty to avoid exceptions.

Edit: another similar way that is more elegant:

```
var ext = parts.splice(-1).join();
var flename = parts.join(".");
```

Note that unlike the first approach, this will actually change the array `parts` so don't use it afterwards.

Comment: and what about filename without extension.. imean `filename` for `filename.txt`... Could you tell mehow to get that also.. :)

Comment: @blaster cheers see my new edit as well to avoid chance for errors. This is my final answer now.. :)

Comment: @Shadow, why not `var ext = parts.splice(-1).join();` and `var filename = parts.join(".");`?

Comment: @Marcus because I wasn't familiar with `splice` enough, just recently began using `slice` actually. Thanks for the suggestion, will give it quick test and add to the answer. :)

Comment: @Shadow, actually using only `var ext = parts.pop();` should do the trick :)

Comment: @Marcus yeah, but `splice` is so much cooler! ;)

Comment: @Shadow, haha! `splice` might be cooler, but `pop` is more correct ;)

Comment: @Marcus well, there is now another answer with exactly that. So I'll leave my answer as is. :)

Answer (score 5):

Just so you get some alternatives, you can extract it with regular expressions too:

```
var full = "filename.ext.txt";

// Get all characters before the last dot
var filename = /.*(?=\.)/.exec(full);

// Get the part without dots on the end
var extension = /[^\.]*$/.exec(full);

// If there are no dots in the full name, filename will be empty and extension
// will contain the whole filename. Do some extra processing:
if(!filename){
    filename = full;
    extension = '';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var ext = 'hibernate.cfg.xml';

var index = ext.lastIndexOf('.');// .xml

alert(ext.substring(index+1)); // xml
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var parts = file.split('.')
  , ext = (parts.length > 1 ? parts.pop() : null)
  , filename = parts.join('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

If `file` always contains at least one dot, you can use:

```
var ext = file.slice(file.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
var filename = file.slice(0,file.lastIndexOf("."));
```

And in a more general case, where `file` might contain no dot:

```
var ext = file.indexOf(".")<0?"":file.slice(file.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
var filename = file.indexOf(".")<0?file:file.slice(0,file.lastIndexOf("."));
```

And last, just for the sake of beautiful code:

```
var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

if (lastDotIndex == -1) {    // Handles the case where there is no dot in "file"

    var fileExtension = "";
    var fileNameWithoutExtension = file;

} else {    // Common case 

    var fileExtension = file.slice(lastDotIndex+1);
    var fileNameWithoutExtension = file.slice(0,lastDotIndex);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already gotten numerous working solutions, but I thought I'd contribute with a object-oriented solution that might be useful for more advanced scenarios:

```
var File = function(fname){
    if (typeof fname === "undefined") {
        console.log("You need to pass a filename or path to file");
        return false;
    }
    // Correct slashes
    fname = fname.replace("\\", "/", fname);
    this.org = fname;
    if (fname.lastIndexOf("/")) {
        this.path = fname.substr(0,fname.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        fname = fname.substr(fname.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    }
    this.ext = fname.substr(fname.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    this.name = fname.substr(0, fname.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
var file = new File("/full/path/to/file/foo.bar.baz");
```

Now, access the properties with `file.name`, `file.ext` and `file.path`.